# Hide parent div and replace text in another div

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've made a custom select menu

```
    <span class="depend">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 finder-form__input-value" data-select-dropdown=".finder-form--one">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Select 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 finder-form__input-value" data-select-dropdown=".finder-form--two">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Select 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 finder-form__input-value"  data-select-dropdown=".finder-form--three">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Select 3</a>
        </div>
     </span>
```

here is the dropdown

```
<div class="row finder-form__dropdown finder-form--one hide">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row finder-form__dropdown-list">
            <a href="">bla bla 1</a>
            .....
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row finder-form__dropdown finder-form--two hide">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row finder-form__dropdown-list">
            <a href="">bla bla 2</a>
            ....
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row finder-form__dropdown finder-form--three hide">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row finder-form__dropdown-list">
            <a href="">bla bla 3</a>
            ....
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

my jQuery currently looks like this

```
$("div.finder-form__dropdown-list a")
.on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //hide current div and unhide next matched div
    $(".finder-form__dropdown")
    .addClass("hide")
    .next()
    .toggleClass("hide");

    //replace text in select div
    $(".finder-form__input-value a")
    .text($(this).text()); 
});
```

I'm trying to get the parent `<div class="finder-form__dropdown">` of the clicked `href` to hide when `href` is clicked. then the text of the `href` will replace the text in `Select 1`

`bla bla 1` will text replace `select 1`, `bla bla 2` will text replace `select 2` and so on.

Also **unhide** the next `<div>` with class `finder-form__dropdown`

Comment: The div with 'Select 1' has class car-finder-form__input-value, not finder-form__input-value. You need to park the car somewhere :)

Comment: @AlivetoDie yeah, but how do i get it from the drop down div? create another data-attribute in the dropdown div?